# SSAS cube updating problem

Tags: ssis, ssas, cube

I have created a SSAS project and it works perfectly fine my cubes, data-sources and such first time I deploy the cube, but if I change the data in my database and I click Cube>Process in BIDS it will not reflect the new changes even though when I retrieve the table data in SQL server Management Studio the table shows my data is changed.

I have also tried updating the cube in SSIS package using the Analysis Services Processing Task. However, the changes in my underlying data is not shown. It stays the same. Can anybody give me the few possible scenarios that can cause this problem.
Much appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to verify that the datasource ON THE SERVER (not locally on your dev machine) is set to the correct database.

Comment: i have found out the problem. The cube will only update the fact tables when i perform any deployment process. However when i manualy add related dimentions to the cube while processing it manualy the changes will take effect. I even Created several other cubes to see if i have missed a step during cube creation to add related dimentions. But i have added the dimentions already. what am i missing?

Comment: Are you processing when you refresh the data? To MANUALLY process, connect to the ANALYSIS SERVICES instance using management studio. Expand the databases folder, right click on the desired database and choose "PROCESS." If this is the issue, and you update data daily, you need to set up a job to process daily.

Answer (score 1):

Are you processing the whole project or just the cube? I noticed that I have to process the top level item in the solution explorer. Processing just the cube was not enough.

Do you get any error messages?

Try processing the dimensions first and then process the cube.

I am not an expert myself, but I understood that there is a difference between updating ("process") and "deploy".

So when you create or add dimensions you will first have to deploy the cube to the analysis server and then process it.

Later when there is new data in your datasource, you can just process the cube (it's already deployed) to update the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Identify which Dimension or Fact Table data you have updated.
2. Goto the SSAS project you have created in Visual Studio for the CUBE.
3. In the Solution Explorer expand Dimensions folder.
4. Right Click the Dimension or Dimension related fact table for which data is updated and Click on Process.
5. Then once the Process window is opened then do confirm in the window then Object Name =  and Process Option = "Process Update".
6. Then Click on run on the bottom of the Process window.
7. Verify the process is succeed, if failed then fix the errors.
8. Go to Browser Tab of the CUBE and check the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes made to the cube structure i.e. adding new measure(s) or business intel. will reflect merely after processing the cube, there is no need to deploy the whole project again. However if any changes are made in underlying data or data structure, then the whole project needs to be deployed.

Changes can be seen right after processing/deployment in Cube>Browser but will take some time to be realized in SSRS because of caching.